# Component diagram for WAR file?

Tags: uml, component-diagram

Let say there's web project which is packed as war file. That project has dependencies on several libraries.

How to show those dependencies without specifying which inner component of that war file uses which library?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool? or for a how-to when it comes to uml modelling ?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind No, I'm looking for a how-to. A proper way to represent the situation on a component diagram.

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer below with additional information for the uml component diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you ask for uml how-to over the tool I edited my answer.

I think the component diagram is self described as it is. I would model it pretty clean like below, without knowing much about your system, language used, complexity or the size...
Most UML people would not have any problem to understand the WAR file from a model like this.

(below I did an example of something let us call for my web orders online web application)

[image: component diagram]

You can specify inner components of an component in deeper levels. Like the << Java Application >> you could e.g. add it in a higher level component as << "Web application server component" >>, which is in a << JVM component >>.

For more reading check [The Component Diagram (IBM)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/dec04/bell/) - read about Showing a component's internal structure

[**Older answer**]

When it comes to tools I would suggest that you take a look at [**JBoss Tattletale**](http://tattletale.jboss.org/).

It is really powerful and easy to use.

The tool will provide you with reports that can help you

- **Identify dependencies between JAR files**
- Find missing classes from the classpath
- Spot if a class/package is located in multiple JAR files
- Spot if the same JAR file is located in multiple locations
- With a list of what each JAR file requires and provides
- Verify the SerialVersionUID of a class
- Find similar JAR files that have different version numbers
- Find JAR files without a version number
- Find unused JAR archives
- Identify sealed / signed JAR archives
- Locate a class in a JAR file
- Get the OSGi status of your project
- Remove black listed API usage
- And generate the same reports for your **.WAR** and **.EAR** archives

Comment: @Alex see also [uml-diagrams.org: UML Package Diagrams Overview](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams-overview.html)

Comment: Good that you mention this too +1. The package diagram is useful too, when showing more package relation in your system. This will give good overview before diving into the class diagrams. this diagram can also be generated with different tools, reverse engineered. But in your package diagram you wont show external libs.